# Force open links in same window on same domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

could someone help me with this problem.

There is requirement to open all links when they are on external domains in _blank. But links in same domain must be opened in same window. I having issue, because I working in 2 domains one is https://www and other just http:// without www, how to open link in same windows on link without www?

```
 function externalLinks() {
    var h = window.location.host;
    jQuery("a[href^='http']").not("[href*='" + h +   "']").not(".forceSameWindow").attr('target', '_blank');
 }
```

now all links exept https://www.something.com opening in blank example: http://something.com

I must do this in jquery/js. I done this by doing hardcoded domain, but what do do nicely!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just change

```
var h = window.location.host;
```

to

```
var h = window.location.host.replace(/^www/,'');
```

that way it doesn't matter if you are on the `www` host or not

Answer (score 0):

You have to force apache to add www.

Add this to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.your_domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your_domain.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Visgi čia  EN saitas, tai ir EN rašom.

Answer (score 0):

```
var externalLinks = function(){
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  var length = anchors.length;
  for(var i=0; i<length;i++){
    var href = anchor[i].href;
    if(href.indexOf('http://h4kr.com/') || href.indexOf('http://www.h4kr.com/')){
      return;
    }
    else{
      anchor[i].target='_blank';
    }
  }
};
```

This should work :)

Answer (score 0):

This is based off your original post

```
$("a").each(function($a){
    $a=$(this);
    if(!~this.href.indexOf(document.location.host)||!$a.hasClass('forceSameWindow')){
        $a.attr('target','_blank');
    }
})
```

Assuming all links are not set up to `_blank` initially